# Clear Javascript Message Box from VBA

Tags: javascript, html, vba, ms-access

In controlling a website (with VBA), and attempting to delete all of the selected items in a table, I get a Javascript pop-up which asks me if I really want to delete all of them (OK or Cancel). When this pops up, my vba code stops, and will not do anything else, until a human clicks the button.

I have researched this quite a bit, and it seems that changing the onClick event for the HTML button would in theory work, but I have been unable to get it to work as of yet.  Below is the HTML code for the button, the subsequent Javascript code, and then my VBA code.

HTML Button

```html
<p>Delete:&nbsp;<input type="button" name="button_Delete" value="Delete" onclick="doDelete('c');">&nbsp;<span class="note">Deletes all selected charts.</span></p> 
                                                          <p>Move to:&nbsp;<select id="select_Lists" name="select_Lists">
```

Javascript after HTML Button

```js
<a href="javascript:doDeleteList('169', 'C');">Delete List</a> |
```

VBA Code to Delete all selected from HTML Table

```
Dim ieDelete as HTMLInputButtonElement
SetieDelete = IE.Document.getElementsByName("button_Delte")(0)
Sleep(500)
ieDelete.removeAttribute("onClick")
Sleep(500)
ieDelete.setAttribute "onClick", "return true;"
Sleep(500)
ieDelete.Click
```

When running the VBA as is, it continues to bring up the Javascript message box.  I have attempted adding **ieDelete.setAttribute "onClick", ""**, but that ends up deleting the entire event, I was not able to do anything to it after that.

And... For the record, I also saw a post describing another option, but I couldn't figure out how to use it in my scenario.  [Respond to Website Message Box by Automating InternetExplorer with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664732/respond-to-website-message-box-by-automating-internetexplorer-with-vba)

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possibly hack the confirmation dialog itself: Overwrite the builtin javascript `confirm` function using the following VBA code before calling `ieDelete.Click`:

```
IE.Document.parentWindow.execScript "confirm = function() { return true; }"
```

(Insert it before your call to `ieDelete.Click`)

This will cause the browser to automatically 'click' OK whenever a confirmation dialog is requested.

PS: This answer assumes that the following:

- The website uses the `confirm` javascript call.
- The version of Internet Explorer you're using supports `execScript`. Other versions might call it `eval` - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536420%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for the compatability notice.

Comment: Incredible!  It worked great.

I assume that it does not permanently disable that message box, but instead only for that run?

Comment: Yes. Only for that run. As soon as you navigate or refresh, the original function is restored.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you again for the help.